# How to update a setup folder?

Tags: updates

I have a folder on my external drive called ***essential software***. In that folder I have some essential setups like 7-Zip, Eclipse, VLC, and etc.

Is there software that will check to see if there is a newer version of each of the files available and if so will replace it with the newer version?

Comment: which OS? i think it's possible, but would be very insecure!

Comment: windows 7 os and it will ask before updating the folder.So how it will insecure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ninite](http://ninite.com/). You can select from an enormous range of software and have the Ninite installer grab them for you, ensuring that they're up-to-date. Additionally, you don't need to store the installers anywhere, which is nice.

Comment: Mmm, the same as my response, but about 1 hour later :) I do prefer LiberKey, so I have not mentioned Ninite, but it was implicit in my answer.

Comment: I know, I wasn't trying to 'steal' your answer, just suggesting an alternative. I up-voted yours as well as posting this one. :)

Answer (score 3):

Forget old installers (well, for essential softwares you can)!

Use softwares like [LiberKey](http://www.liberkey.com/en.html). With it, for example, you can:

- install a lot of essential programs
- use as portable application (all user data and programs are stored in LiberKey foder; you can copy or move that folder to a pendrive or another computer easily)
- **stay up-to-date with all installed applications**, since LiberKey will manage updates for every program
- use LiberKey catalog as you use your folder of essential programs - but **the installers will be allways "updated in the cloud"**